# SQL query - public and private objects of package x

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to build a query that lists the available objects(procedures and functions) of a PL/SQL package, with an additional column, privacy_level, that shows whether that object exists in both body and spec(is public), or in the body only(is private).

After browsing a little, I only found this query (which returns no rows)

```
select name, 
       type,
       decode(usage,'DECLARATION', 'body only', 'DEFINITION', 'spec and body', usage) defined_on,
       line body_line
  from all_identifiers ui
  where type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
  and usage_context_id = (select usage_id
    from user_identifiers
      where object_name = ui.object_name
        and object_type = ui.object_type
        and usage_context_id = 0)
  --and object_name = 'PACKAGE_NAME'
  --and object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
  order by name;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That seems to work (can't demo without adding a non-answer). Did you do `alter session set plscope_settings = 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL';` before compiling your packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is against `all_identifiers`, which is part of [the PL/Scope tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_plscope.htm). That system view only shows data for objects that were compiled with the appropriate settings:

> By default, PL/Scope does not collect data for identifiers in the PL/SQL source program. To have PL/Scope collect data for all identifiers in the PL/SQL source program, including identifiers in package bodies, set the PL/SQL compilation parameter `PLSCOPE_SETTINGS` to `'IDENTIFIERS:ALL'`.

If I create a package with private and public subprograms with the default settings:

```
create package p42 as
  procedure public_proc;
  function public_func return number;
end p42;
/

create package body p42 as
  procedure public_proc is
  begin
    null;
  end public_proc;

  function public_func return number is
  begin
    return 42;
  end public_func;

  procedure private_proc is
  begin
    null;
  end private_proc;

  function private_func return number is
  begin
    return 42;
  end private_func;
end p42;
/
```

then your using your query finds nothing:

```
select name, 
...
  order by name;

no rows selected
```

If I had set `PLSCOPE_SETTINGS` before creating them then they would be shown; assuming you don't want to fully recreate everything you can recompile your packages after changing the setting:

```
alter session set plscope_settings = 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

Session altered.

alter package p42 compile;

Package P42 altered.
```

Now your query gets:

```
NAME                           TYPE               DEFINED_ON     BODY_LINE
------------------------------ ------------------ ------------- ----------
PRIVATE_FUNC                   FUNCTION           body only             17
PRIVATE_PROC                   PROCEDURE          body only             12
PUBLIC_FUNC                    FUNCTION           body only              3
PUBLIC_FUNC                    FUNCTION           spec and body          7
PUBLIC_PROC                    PROCEDURE          body only              2
PUBLIC_PROC                    PROCEDURE          spec and body          2

6 rows selected.
```

Something like this might be closer to what you said you were trying to achieve though, using the fact that private subprograms only appear in the table as part of the body:

```
select object_name, type, name,
  case min(object_type) when 'PACKAGE BODY' then 'PRIVATE' else 'PUBLIC' end as privacy_level
from user_identifiers
where object_type in ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY')
and type in ('FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE')
group by object_name, type, name
order by object_name, name;

OBJECT_NAME     TYPE               NAME            PRIVACY
--------------- ------------------ --------------- -------
P42             FUNCTION           PRIVATE_FUNC    PRIVATE
P42             PROCEDURE          PRIVATE_PROC    PRIVATE
P42             FUNCTION           PUBLIC_FUNC     PUBLIC 
P42             PROCEDURE          PUBLIC_PROC     PUBLIC
```

If you want to find this information for all objects you can either recompile them individually, or recompile the whole schema:

```
exec dbms_utility.compile_schema(user);
```

But be aware that if any of your package has state then existing sessions may error when they call them (so you might want to do that during downtime), and if anyone compiles anything without explicitly altering their session then those objects will not be shown by you query (unless you set it at database level, which may be too much overhead).

Comment: Do you know if there is any overhead at runtime to compiling with 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL' ? I'm not worried about the possibly longer compile time just the run-time.

Comment: @BriteSponge - not that I know of, and it seems unlikely. There may not even be a significant amount of overhead at compile time, but may be noticeable for large packages, and could add up over a development cycle - just something to think about before enabling with `alter system`. There is [some storage cost](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_plscope.htm#BABDHFIF) too, but again probably not significant.

Comment: I'll investigate the PLScope stuff  I think with a view to proposing that we turn it on at the DB level. Sounds like it has the potential to be useful at little to no cost.