# To extract private arguments details from procedure and function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where I need to retrieve arguments, their data type, mode (IN/OUT) of private function n procedure define in package similar like dba_argument table.

Comment: [Possibly also relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44589749/266304) if you're trying to get both public and private subprogram info.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Just like DBA_ARGUMENTS gives me all the details like arguments_name , argument data type, mode in which argument (IN/OUT). I need similar block for private function/procedure as well.